# Elasticsearch Phrase Suggestion

Tags: elasticsearch

The elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html) states:

> In practice this suggester will be able to make better decisions about which tokens to pick based on *co-occurence* and frequencies.

I have a document in my index that has a *name* field with content `Bella Tank`.

To test the phrase suggester, I send the following query:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "suggest" : {
    "text" : "Bell Tank",
    "suggestion": {
      "phrase": {
        "field": "name",
        "size": 3
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And the 3 suggestions I receive are:

```
"suggest" : {
  "suggestion" : [ {
    "text" : "Bell Tank",
    "offset" : 0,
    "length" : 9,
    "options" : [ {
      "text" : "ball tank",
      "score" : 0.03721739
    }, {
      "text" : "bella tank",
      "score" : 0.03721739
    }, {
      "text" : "bess tank",
      "score" : 0.034840018
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

As you can see, `ball tank` and `bella tank` suggestions have the same score, even though only `bella tank` exists in my index. It doesn't seem to care about co-occurence of tokens at all.

Is my only choice here to create a non-analyzed version of `name` using [multifields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) or am I doing this all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an [shingle filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) on the field you are suggesting against. Multifields are great for this because you may not want to *search* with the shingles. You can use up to 3 for the `max_shingle_size`.

Its certainly a [bug](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13283) that the docs don't mention this very prominently.

Look at how [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=cirrus-settings-dump&format=json&formatversion=2) sets up its suggest analyzer. Its not perfect but its a good start.